# What is a Ping Pong Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word satisfies a certain property, it is called a Ping Pong Word™. Find out what the rule is given the following examples.

| Ping Pong Words™ | Not Ping Pong Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DUCK | GOOSE |
| VISUAL | OPTICAL |
| CORNFIELD | PUMPKIN |
| QUANTITY | QUALITY |
| NEIGHBOR | FRIEND |
| WORLD | EARTH |
| TURKEY | CHICKEN |
| EIGHT | NINE |
| ENCHANTMENT | WITCHCRAFT |

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A Ping Pong Word™ is a word that

> requires alternating hands to type on a QWERTY keyboard, using the convention to type Y on the right hand, B on the left. (More specifically: left hand keys are QWERTASDFGZXCVB and right hand keys are YUIOPHJKLNM.)